# Is it possible to use unicode combining characters to combine arbitrary characters?

Tags: unicode

Is it possible to use unicode combining characters to for example make the characters `x` and `y` appear to be partially overlapping each other?

I know that in layout systems like CSS there are other ways to achieve this, but I specifically want to know if its possible with just unicode so I can for example do it in Slack messages.

Comment: The real answer involves [creating your own custom characters](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.unicode/2012/02/msg3347.html).

Comment: Huh...I've done that before, didn't know you could shift into another letter's space with custom characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no Unicode mechanism to make arbitrary letters overlap each other. You can put an `x` *above* a `y` using the character U+036F COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER X like so: yͯ, but that’s about it.

Latin letters partially overlapping each other serves no semantic function, so it is not part of the Unicode standard. And if it was found to be used to convey actual meaning in some writing system, it would most likely not be encoded as a generalised mechanism but as individual characters representing specific such ligatures.

The Unicode Consortium does not consider styling features like that to be part of plain text. That is also why those bold and italic mathematical letters you sometimes see on Twitter (, ,  etc.) aren’t implemented as the base letters plus some style modifiers, but as [separate character codes](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf) entirely. A character that means “display the preceding letter as bold” would have been too general; non-crucial style variation should be dealt with through higher-level protocols (like the CSS you mentioned) which are much more powerful and enjoy more widespread support anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks, that gives me an answer...I didn't have a *great* use case and...well no...this isn't a great use case at all, but I just wanted to see if I could make and go closer so that the pointer goes into...oh you get it. Actually semantic meaning, technically! Not a great use case.

Comment: There is a use case with emojis. I just wanted to show a cloudy night in a GTK label, without the need for another, 2nd cumbersome Overlay widget -- and with that show a moon emoji overlayed with a cloud emoji. Since that's not possible I now have to fight GTK 3s delicate layout and transparency system to get it working with 2 overlays.

Comment: Yes, in my case, I wanted to combine a circle emoji with a check mark emoji. Which, I think, is perfectly reasonable. Besides, with giving in to sexist and racist bullies by implementing the ability to be racist and sexist by picking a skin color or gender (even when it is literally invisible), they are already way past their principles, and should just do it already, and turn Unicode into a full image editing language. XD